# Retrieve Jason object with Sqlite3

Tags: json, sqlite

Is there a way to retrieve a Json object in Sqlite3?

I see lots of examples how to get the object field by field, but I just want the whole thing,

I insert it into a one column (rec) table using json(data)

If I retrieve using select rec from...
I get an object, but it’s { rec: string}, so I have to JSON.parse(data.rec)..  Fine with one row, but I would rather not iterate thru each row to do the conversion if SQLite can do it for me

Comment: Give us a table definition and examples of the data stored in it? And how you want the results to be formatted?

Comment: Never mind - on bus ride home I realized why what I was asking for made no sense - JSON objects are hierarchical.